# Abstract algebra basic Group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that if $G=gp(x)$ and $G$ is of finite order $r$, and $s$ is coprime to $r$( i.e. the $\gcd$ of $r$ and $s$ is $1$) then $gp(x^s)=G$.

I think to show this I need to:

Let $y\in G$
Show $y\in gp(x^s)$

Conversely,Let $y\in gp(x^s)$
show $y\in G$

but I am not sure how to show the baby steps using the given info. The question should only use very basic group theory.

Comment: use LaTeX,if you want others to clearly understand your problem.

Comment: what is $gp(x)$??

Comment: still, can't read it, what is gp(x)?

Comment: The $E$'s you have written all over the place, do you mean $\in$, by any chance? If so, the command is `\in`. I assume $gp(x)$ means $\langle x\rangle$, the cyclic group generated by $x$.

Comment: G=gp(x), this was all the given information. but I think G is a group so gp(x) should be a group as well.

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam $gp(x)$ was a relatively common notation for the group generated by the element $x$, so $gp(x)=\langle x\rangle$. I think it has slipped out of usage now - I have only seen it in old papers and books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, $G$ is the group generated by $x$, which I'd prefer to denote $\langle x \rangle$.  We also know $|\langle x \rangle|=r$.  We want to show that $\langle x \rangle=\langle x^s \rangle$ whenever $\gcd(s,r)=1$.  It is sufficient to show $x \in \langle x^s \rangle$, since this implies $\langle x \rangle \leq \langle x^s \rangle \leq \langle x \rangle$.

To do this, we use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find integers $a,b$ for which $ar+bs=1$, then note that $x=x^{ar+bs}=x^{bs} \in \langle x^s \rangle$.

Comment: how did you go from x^ar+bs to x^bs?

Comment: $x=x^{ar+bs}$ since $ar+bs=1$, and $x^{ar+bs}=x^{ar}x^{bs}=x^{bs}$ since $x^{ar}=1$, since $x$ has order $r$.